# Django test doesn't update model

Tags: django

Probably something simple but its bugging me that one of my tests is failing.

I have a view that handles a POST request from a form to edit a model. I cant see why this test is failing (name does not change):

```
def test_edit_club_view(self):

    """
    Test changes can be made to an existing club through a post request to the edit_club view.
    """

    new_club = Club.objects.create(
        name = "new club name unique"
    )

    self.client.post("/clubs/edit/{}/".format(new_club.pk), data = {"name": "edited_club_name"})
    self.assertEqual(new_club.name, "edited_club_name")
```

The test for the form passes:

```
def test_club_can_be_changed_through_form(self):

    """
    Test the ClubForm can make changes to an existing club in the database.
    """

    form_data = {
        "name": "new club name"
    }

    add_club_form = ClubForm(data = form_data, instance = self.existing_club)
    add_club_form.save()
    self.assertEqual(self.existing_club.name, "new club name")
```

Also, if I print the values for the `name` field in the view, it appears to be changed there, but not reflected in the test case.

```
AssertionError: 'new club name unique' != 'edited_club_name'
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to reload `new_club` from the database after the post.

```
new_club.refresh_from_db()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick solve!
I'll accept as soon as it'll let me

Comment: I come back to this answer every month. Thank you